# Consturcting a sprite bitmap from mutliple partial sprties across sheets

Tags: android

First of all, I am not using engine and this is for Android. Bear with me if I use incorrect lingo as I am not experienced in game dev (but I am trying)

I am being provided multiple sprite sheets. Each sheet represent the animation of one part of a warrior (ie. Head sheet, arm sheet, leg sheet and body sheet).

I intend to basically construct the frames of the warrior using the sprite sheets. I basically thought of the following. For every Frame, I will create a bitmap that consists of the different parts ( by extracting the correct part from every sheet and placing it in the intended x/y position). That way every bitmap represent a frame.

Is my approach correct? Is there different way/recommended way to do this?

Please share your advice ( anything but game engine as it is tool late to use)

Thank you

PS: I need the end result to be a bitmap because at the end, I will supplying a bitmap to another function at once every 200ms.

Comment: What are you using to draw to the screen?

Comment: I am basically using the bitmap for the marker on the google map. I call the fromBitmap on the marker in a loop and I pass to it different bitmap in every loop to show one frame of the image. I am thinking of using canvas to do the the "bitmap image construction"